# Remove <br/> from xmlnode

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

My XML could look like this:

```
<div>
    <p>
       First Text
        <br/>
       Second Text
    </p>
</div>
```

Loading the xml-file, going through all nodes with the following code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filepath);

foreach (XmlNode row in doc.SelectNodes("/div/p"))
{
    string subtext = row.InnerText;
    richtextbox.AppendText(subtext + "\n");
}
```

The result will always look like this:

```
First TextSecond Text
```

Now the problem obviously is, that there's no space (or even a line break) between the first & second text. So, is there a way to replace that `<br/>` with a space/line break?

Comment: While I don't know how `XMLDocument.Load` attempts to parse this, HTML is not XML. HTML is a subset of SGML, XML is also a subset of SGML.
You should instead use a HTML parser or only load XML.

Comment: You have html not xml.  Xml methods will only work on some html files.   Use html library instead of an xml library.

Comment: @CameronAavik @jdweng - if it was HTML the br would be  `<br>` and not `<br/>` (self closing). As it stands that is well formed XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath:

```
doc.SelectNodes("/div/p/text()")
```

It gives you two text nodes before and after `br` tag.

Comment: This sadly doesn't work in my case because as you said, it creates two text nodes. I need that node as a whole, without splitting it up.